# ViewModel not getting cleared in Navigation navigate and live data in viewmodel stays alive

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

So, I have implemented single activity with multiple fragments pattern using Navigation. I used viewmodel for each fragment for non-ui operatios.

The problem is when you navigate using `findNavController().navigate()`, the fragment is not actually destroyed. Only the `onDestroyView` is called. So, the fragment's onDestroy never gets called and subsequently the viewmodel doesn't get cleared and so the LiveData observer also remains alive and when i come back to the fragment the observer is created again and so live data is observed twice. Once with the old data that it holds and second with the new data from some operations.

For example,
I have fragment**A** and fragment**B**

**A** shows a list and **B** you can add something which will be shown in the list. maybe fetching new data from api in fragment **B** to be shown in **A**.

So, when i go back from fragment **B** to **A** the observer gets called twice first with old data then second with the updated data. In the end the list shows correct data but I don't want two observers happening.

I have followed this article
https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/architecture-components-pitfalls-part-1-9300dd969808

and tried to use `viewLifeCycleOwner` instead of `this` but that does not help and issue still exists.

I also tried removing observer before observing :

```
vm.ld.removeObservers(this)
vm.ld.observe(viewLifeCyclerOwner, observer)
```

still the issue remains.

(I tried removing observer in `onDestroyView` also, still the issue remains.)

The only work around i found is manually calling the viewmodel `onCleared` in `onDestroyView` and clearing the livedata.

**In fragment onDestroyView**

```
vm.clear()
```

**In viewmodel**

```
fun clear() = onCleared()

override fun onCleared() {
  //do stuff
}
```

Now, this solves my issue. But i feel this is not a solid solution and there can be a better way to do this. I would be glad if anybody can shed a light on this one. Thanks.

Comment: bro u have the solution? cause i have the same issue

Comment: you can try the solution that I have used above. But note that this is not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 6):

I wasted a couple of days troubleshooting a similar issue.  Double check how your VM is initialized:

```kotlin
val myVm: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

vs.

```kotlin
val myVm: MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

If you use the `by activityViewModels()` delegate, you are instructing Android to tie the lifetime of the VM to the host activity rather than the current Fragment.  Thus, your VM won't be cleared even when the fragment is destroyed. I learned this the hard way.  Switching back to the `by viewModels()` delegate leaves the VM scoped to the lifetime of the Fragment. When the fragment is destroyed, if it's the only observer, the VM will clear.

I was totally confused by the `this` vs. `viewLifecycleOwner` target when observing. Apparently, the choice of target has only to do with whether you intend to manually control presenting the dialog of a DialogFragment. Another gem of confusion.

In your case, if you're switching between fragments and `onDestroy` isn't being called, it could also be because fragments are being retained.  For example, `ViewPager2` has `offscreenPageLimit`, which instructs Android to keep hidden fragments in memory as you switch pages, adding even further to this mess of having to know absolutely everything about everything just to use the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `viewModelStore.clear()` in your fragment, and then override `onCleared()` in ViewModel for dispose what your need

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of your livedata to null in `onDestroyView`.

example :

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
   super.onDestroyView()
   vm.ld.value = null
}
```

or

```
in ViewModel

fun resetLiveData() {
  _ld.value = null
}

in Fragment

override fun onDestroyView() {
   super.onDestroyView()
   vm.resetLiveData()
}
```